# Url in the Address bar with php, or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

## .htaccess

```
    RewriteRule ^info/{0,1}$  index.php?page=info [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login/{0,1}$  index.php?page=login [QSA,L]
```

## the same : index = index/

```
RewriteRule ^info/?$ $1
RewriteRule ^login/?$ $1
```

javascript:

```js
    reg_e=/#$/; if(!window.location.href.match(reg_e)) { 
 window.location.href = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"#";}
```

it's working... good
I have problem that
when someone try to add '/' or any at the final url http://example.com/info/# will return [http://example.com/info#](http://example.com/info/#) or http://example.com/info/# but page will change nothing ?
Can you help me establish any rules for none breaking web addresses at ends of lines?

example : [http://example.com/info#](http://example.com/info/#) <- base url

[http://example.com/info/#](http://[http://example.com/info/#) to be => [http://example.com/info#](http://example.com/login#)

or : [http://example.com/info/#](http://example.com/login#) <= or if anyone add '/@-' e.tc. the web will be nothing change.

And when I click 'info' and add '/' [http://example.com/info/#, it's ok. but i click other link it will be : 
[http://example.com/info/login#](http://[http://example.com/info/#) <- RewriteRule ^login/?$ $1
 instead of: [[http://example.com/login/#](http://[http://example.com/info/#)

if remove #RewriteRule ^login/?$ $1 ->> http://example.com/login# when add '/' handle =>  css wont load.

'info' and 'login are the same level in index folder.

i'd tried "`<base href='/' />` but not working.

how to have a safe url? thanks your opions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you want here but it seems as though you want a link to redirect from base URL and not the relative URL.

Say your link is this:

```
<a href="login">Login</a>
```

Try this instead

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

The `/` at the beginning will say to go back to the base URL and start from there. Let me know if I missed the point completely though :)